# How to return 'Integer' type for ResponseEntity<> and get the result on api page?

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot, rest, spring-mvc

I just started working on a spring-boot application (Java) in MVC. In the controller class,

```
@GetMapping("/{id}/age")
public ResponseEntity<Integer> getStudentAge(@PathVariable Long id) {
    Integer age = studentService.retrieveAgeById(id);
    return new ResponseEntity<Integer>(age, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

With a simple SQL data, as simple as this:
`INSERT INTO student (id, name, age, gender) VALUES (1, 'Rio', 5, 'Male');`
When I run the application and check the webpage with path: http://localhost:8080/1/age
I get a response in which age is NOT printed:
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i15YC.png)

The Query used in repository package is:

```
@Query("select d.id, d.age from Student d where d.id=:id")
Integer findAgeById(Long id);
```

Also, the requests for student name, gender(Type:String) is successful. But, the request for age (Type:Integer) is not producing similar results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adapt your SELECT query to:

```
@Query("select d.age from Student d where d.id = :id")
Integer findAgeById(@Param("id") Long id);
```

The query in your question will map the first field from your SELECT to the type of your method, an as you can see, that is your Student ID.

You also could to provide a `@Param` in your method declaration, because according to [this guide](https://baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-query):

> A query with named parameters is easier to read and is less error-prone in case the query needs to be refactored.

If you want to extact both the ID and the age, you can return your entire `Student` entity, and use that. Another option is to use a [projection](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-projections) but I really don't believe your use-case is advanced enough to benefit from this.

Comment: Hi, 
That answered the question. But, what if I wanted both the Id and the age to printed on the result page ? What should the return type of method be in that case? For ex:
`@Query("select d.id, d.age from Student d where d.id = :id")
<Type> findAgeById(@Param("id") Long id);`